# How to get number output from pexpect

Tags: python, pexpect

I'm using pexpect to handle two programs made by C.

The problem is that I have to get an integer. I want to have two integers printed from two programs, but all I know is `pexpect.expect(['0','1','...','9'])`. I want to get whole integer (with int scale). How can I get this?

(Expected code)

```
cmd_1 = pexpect.spawn('./program1')
cmd_2 = pexpect.spawn('./program2')
n_1 = pexpect.expect('something')
n_2 = pexpect.expect('something')
print("Number 1 : {} Number 2 : {}".format(n_1,n_2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.expect()` uses regular expressions.  Therefore, use either `\\d` or `[0-9]`.  You will still need to convert it to an integer, however.  One more thing: it should be `cmd1.expect` and `cmd2.expect`, not `pexpect.expect`

Comment: pexpect.expect was a mistake. Thks.